# php image generating error cant display because it contain errors

Tags: php

I am trying to change the color of an transparent image using gd library i am new to gd library on compile code it gives error 
The Image http://localhost/gdlib/gd.php cant display because it containes error
this is my code for generating png image

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: image/png");
$source=imagecreatefrompng('ff6600.png');    // Source
$width=imagesx($source);    $height=imagesy($source);

$im = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);    // Our negative img in the making
$test = imagecolorallocate($im, 25,25,112);
for($y=0; $y < $height; $y++) {
    for($x=0; $x < $width; $x++) {

    $colors=imagecolorsforindex($source, imagecolorat($source, $x,$y));
        $test=imagecolorallocate($im, 25,25,112);
        imagesetpixel($im,$x, $y, $test);
    }
}
$imgname = time()."tiidi.png";

imagepng($im, $imgname);  
imagedestroy($im);



?>
```

Comment: @donald123 because of the header he sets, the browser will think it is corrupted an will display that exect error. Post owner: if you temporarily disable the header you can see the error

Answer (score 1):

If you comment out the header function on the top you may see the error message about that. I see no error with that code on my image. Is that the whole code and do tou output something before creating the image (or after that)?

Comment: Sorry it was my fault, didn't notice that the GD extension isn't installed on my server, just installed that.

Answer (score 1):

By `imagepng($im, $imgname);` you only save your image to file.

Just add another `imagepng($im)` , which without filename parameter will output the image:

```
imagepng($im, $imgname);
imagepng($im);  
imagedestroy($im);
```

I checked it and it works for me. Also make sure you don't output anything before header function.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the php eng tag from the code  and it works fine i dont know why does it generate error